# How to loop through days array starting from the current date

Tags: javascript

I've built a simple app that prints days from an array. When you click the button, you print another day and another etc. However, when I add a starting point - the current day - I cannot loop through following days.

```js
const days = [
  "Monday ",
  "Tuesday ",
  "Wednesday ",
  "Thursday ",
  "Friday ",
  "Saturday ",
  "Sunday ",
];

const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");

let d = new Date();
let currentDay = d.getDay();

const list = document.querySelector("#list");
let i = 0;

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let newEl = document.createElement("li");

  newEl.textContent = days[currentDay];
  // this is the place where I'm stuck
  // I cannot write: days[currentDay]++

  i++;
  if (i >= days.length) i = 0;
  list.append(newEl);
});
```

```html
<h2>Days of the week:</h2>
<ul id="list"></ul>
<button id="btn">Add one more day</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `days[currentDay]`. But since `currentDay` does not change, it won't work

---

Lets go this way:

1. After getting `currentDay`, set `i` to `currentDay` (this is ok since your array has the correct order, we could use `indexOf` aswell.
2. Use `i` as index to show the date:

```js
const days = [
  "Monday ",
  "Tuesday ",
  "Wednesday ",
  "Thursday ",
  "Friday ",
  "Saturday ",
  "Sunday ",
];

const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");

let d = new Date();
let currentDay = d.getDay();

const list = document.querySelector("#list");
let i = currentDay;

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {

  let newEl = document.createElement("li");

  newEl.textContent = days[i];

  i++;
  if (i >= days.length) i = 0;
  list.append(newEl);
});
```

```html
<h2>Days of the week:</h2>
<ul id="list"></ul>
<button id="btn">Add one more day</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Ostone() you really helped. I also need to change the order of days - starting from Sunday as 0.

Answer (score 2):

The **getDay()** method returns the day of the week where 0 represents Sunday

Perhaps all you have to do is make Sunday the first element of the array

Please try the following code

```
const days = [
    "Sun",
    "Mon",
    "Tue",
    "Wed",
    "Thu",
    "Fri",
    "Sat",
];

var currentDay = new Date().getDay();  // Sun = 0, Mon = 1, ..., Sat = 6 

console.log(days[currentDay]);

console.log(days[currentDay + 1]);
```

Hopefully I did not misunderstand your question

Fabio

Comment: You're right. Thanks Fabio, I figured that out later after I run code proposed by Ostone().

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the placement of `++` that you were trying. Also you don't require an extra variable `i`

```
const days = [
  "Monday ",
  "Tuesday ",
  "Wednesday ",
  "Thursday ",
  "Friday ",
  "Saturday ",
  "Sunday ",
];

const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");

let d = new Date();
let currentDay = d.getDay();

const list = document.querySelector("#list");

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let newEl = document.createElement("li");

  newEl.textContent = days[currentDay++];
 
  if (currentDay >= days.length) currentDay = 0;
  list.append(newEl);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing **i** but you never change the **currentDay**.

In your function, remove **i** and use **currentDay** instead.

Here is the code :

```
const days = [
    "Monday ",
    "Tuesday ",
    "Wednesday ",
    "Thursday ",
    "Friday ",
    "Saturday ",
    "Sunday ",
];

const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");

let d = new Date();
let currentDay = d.getDay();

const list = document.querySelector("#list");

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {

    currentDay++; // add 1 to currentDay
    if (currentDay > days.length) currentDay = 0; // reset currentDay to 0 each week

    let newEl = document.createElement("li");
    newEl.textContent = days[currentDay];  
    list.append(newEl);
});
```